# htaccess redirect url with subdomain as parameter only for php files and directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I achieved redirects to match the following rules:

1. Everything that ends with .php being redirected to .php?lang=en

   - http://en.d.com/index.php => http://d.com/index.php?lang=en
   - http://en.d.com/zzz.php => http://d.com/zzz.php?lang=en
   - http://en.d.com/folder/index.php => http://d.com/folder/index.php?lang=en
2. Everything that ends with folder being redirect to index.php?lang=en

   - http://en.d.com => http://d.com/index.php?lang=en
   - http://en.d.com/folder => http://d.com/folder/index.php?lang=en
3. **My problem is how do I process request as is without redirect if it contains any file other than *.php in the end:**

   - http://en.d.com/file.xml => http://en.d.com/file.xml
   - http://en.d.com/folder/file.xml => http://en.d.com/folder/file.xml

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !(.*?).php   [nc]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://d.com/$1/index.php?lang=%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
>
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !^/.php   [nc]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://d.com/$1?lang=%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://d.com/$1?lang=%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
>
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://d.com/$1index.php?lang=%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
> ```

Also it would be nice to get feedback regarding my rules or suggestions to improve them.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !^/.php
```

This condition is never met as it checks to see the  uri value is  starting with **/.php** ,

change this to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !^/.*\.php
```